# How to allow users to select text that is in a fancytree node

Tags: fancytree

I tried my best and I am unable to find a way to allow users to be able to select the text that is displayed as a node text in fancytree. I am not talking about selecting the node itself, but to copy the text displayed.

For example, in this fancytree demo page, http://wwwendt.de/tech/fancytree/demo/index.html#sample-configurator.html
in the first node, I would like to highlight and select the text "simple node" and unable to.

Any help is appreciated!
J

Comment: It appears to be caused by this    `.on("selectstart" + ns, "span.fancytree-title", function(event){
   // prevent mouse-drags to select text ranges
   // tree.debug("<span title> got event " + event.type);
   event.preventDefault();`

Answer (score 0):

You could try to define and add a class to the nodes, like that

```
.selectable {
  -webkit-touch-callout: text; /* iOS Safari */
    -webkit-user-select: text; /* Safari */
     -khtml-user-select: text; /* Konqueror HTML */
       -moz-user-select: text; /* Firefox */
        -ms-user-select: text; /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
            user-select: text; /* Non-prefixed version, currently
                                  supported by Chrome and Opera */
}
```

(or define a rule that addresses the current node title selector directly)